# How do you get the geckodriver executable in PATH for Eclipse Neon on MacOSX?

Tags: eclipse, macos, selenium, geckodriver

I am trying to install selenium on mac for webscraping using eclipse neon and getting "'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH." Have tried doing the whole "export PATH=$PATH:usr/local/bin/geckodriver2" command and have also tried updating and downgrading selenium (two different suggestions) I'm at a loss here guys. Anyone have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to update the global path.. We can mention the path programatically.. Just for example below is the code to launch firefox in mac..

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    //SET THE PATH OF THE GECKODRIVER
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/santhoshkumar/Documents/Softwares/geckodriver"); 
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
    driver.get("http://facebook.com"); 
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); 
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.